# RStudio after crash cannot get help/env/plots window to show

Tags: rstudio, admin-rights

After R-Studio crashed I lost the rightmost window and can only see the code and runtime windows when I re-open the project.
  Is there a setting that I can change in R-Studio that allows the help, environment, plots windows ect. to show to the right of the code & runtime windows again? I've tried view menu Show History/Show Plots/Show Environment/Move focus to help but haven't gotten the window back.
  I'm using Windows 10 operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Tools -> Global Options -> Pane Layout and choose the layout of the panes that you want.

Comment: This was useful in that I can move the plot window to one of the left panes in place of a code or console window. I'm still unable to get the right panes to show again.

Comment: You also can do more than move the windows around. You can select which views that you want using the checkboxes below the drop down menus.

Comment: They're selected.  I think that the check boxes are not related to the setting that is causing the problem. Is there possibly a registry key that influences how wide these windows should be?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a rights issue. I get all of my windows back if I run R-Studio in administrator mode.